# Is cfstoredproc.statusCode returned?

Tags: lucee

When ReturnCode=true, it should [populate cfstoredproc.statusCode with the status code returned by the stored procedure.](http://www.iwanttobealandscapearchitect.com/railo-context/doc/tags.cfm?item=cfstoredproc)

But I can only see cached and executionTime.

Comment: this feature also depends on the database server. what product are you connecting to?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Serve 2012

Comment: Can you post together a small example that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that I tested and works. Perhaps the issue is with the way the stored procedure is written or with the JDBC Driver you are using to connect with the database.

Another option you have at hand is to not use the  tag to call the storedprocedure. You can also call stored procedures using the cfquery tag. This often gives more predictable results.

Here is the code for the test procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PTest
@Somename nvarchar(50) = NULL,  -- NULL default value
@SomeResponse nvarchar(50) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
IF @Somename IS NULL
BEGIN
RETURN(1)
END
ELSE
SET @SomeResponse = 'Hello World:' + @Somename;
BEGIN
RETURN(2)
END
```

Then on the coldfusion side using the cfstoredproc tag:

```
<cfstoredproc datasource="yourdatasource" procedure="dbo.PTest" returncode="yes">
<cfprocparam type="in" variable="Somename" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="John Smith">
<cfprocparam type="out" variable="SomeResponse" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfstoredproc>

<cfoutput>
#SomeResponse#
<cfdump var="#cfstoredproc#">
</cfoutput>
```

Using cfquery this would look like this:

```
<cfquery name="qFoo" datasource="yourdatasource">
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @SomeResponse varchar(50), @return_code int;

EXECUTE @return_code = dbo.PTest 'John Smith', @SomeResponse = @SomeResponse OUTPUT

SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT  @return_code as returnCode,
@SomeResponse as someResponse
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
#qFoo.returnCode# | #qFoo.someResponse#
<cfdump var="#qFoo#">
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Keep in mind stored procedures may return multiple resultsets. CFQuery is only capable of handling a *single* resultset, so it not a straight equivalent.  (Personally, my preference is cfstoredproc).  Since this feature should, you may want to post a small repro case. Hopefully someone can test it against the three engines Railo, Lucee and ACF and see if we can figure out why it is working (bug, driver difference, etcetera).